# Topology Manager access denied for the user TRDWCMDEV\MTSUser

Tags: topology-manager

I'm trying to add a Topology Manager Mapping for our publication to our live environment. Yet when I run `Add-TtmMapping` I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Add-TtmMapping -publicationid tcm:0-5-1 -webapplicationid IntranetLive_RootWebApp
Add-TtmMapping : Item of type 'MappingData' can not be saved. Unable to connect to 'net.tcp://localhost:2660' using authentication type 'Windows'. Access is denied for the user TRDWCMDEV\MTSUser.
```

What is the cause of this? I already added the user to the Topology Manager Admin group. MTSUser is the user that has been used to install Web 8.

(I get this error too when using any of the `Remove-Ttm*` cmdlets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the error message, `TRDWCMDEV\MTSUser` does not have access to your Content Manager system.

Comment: Oh, so I should add him as a user? Right, I'll check that. Thanks

Comment: Yes, preferably a sysadmin user. A bit of background: for some operations, Topology Manager will communicate with Content Manager (through the Core Service). It uses the Core Service URL and credentials specified in your CmEnvironment entity (in Topology Manager).  The credentials should be of an existing, enabled User account (with sysadmin privileges).